# X11 forwarding Amazon EC2 significance of sequence number in DISPLAY variable

Tags: ssh, x11, port-forwarding

I am X11 forwarding from an Ubuntu instance hosted in a Amazon EC2 to my localhost. I am able to do the forwarding only when the remote (Amazon EC2) `DISPLAY` variable is set to `localhost:10.0`
I understand that `10` is the sequence number but I am wondering how it is decided. I had tried forwarding `xclock` app and it seems to work only when the sequence number is `10` and nothing else (0,1,2 .. 9 nothing worked).

FWIW, my localhost's `DISPLAY` variable is set to `:0`
Could somebody enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not the sequence number - in X11, the sequence number is the identifier of each request, and is not included in the DISPLAY variable.   It's the identifier of which server to connect to, called the "display number" in the [X11 documentation](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading5).

Comment: @alanc: Thanks for that clarity. I did a little bit of googling before asking the question and the answer in  http://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable seems to have used the wrong term..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connected to your instance you used `ssh` and it created a small server on the remote that listens on port 6010 for connections which are forwarded back over your ssh connection. When you run `DISPLAY=localhost:10 xclock` the application converts 10 to 6010 (an X11 convention) and connects to that local port to get the data sent back to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I tried the command `netstat -an | grep 6010` in the remote Amazon EC2 instance and I could see a tcp `LISTEN` on that port. Shouldn't this listening be happening on the local computer instead (as it seems to be the recipient of the X11 network data)?

Comment: When xclock connects to the remote port, the ssh daemon listening there will send the request back *over your existing connection* to your local ssh which will pass it on to local port 6000 (display :0). It uses the same channel so you dont need to open up an incoming firewall port, for example. You might be able to see some of this if you `ssh -v` to the remote initially.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense to send data over the same channel as ssh rather than open a separate connection.

Answer (score 2):

At least in OpenSSH, the actual numerical offset is determined by a parameter `X11DisplayOffset` in the sshd configuration file (/etc/ssh/sshd_config on Ubuntu):

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

From `man sshd_config`

```
 X11DisplayOffset
         Specifies the first display number available for sshd(8)'s X11
         forwarding.  This prevents sshd from interfering with real X11
         servers.  The default is 10.
```

Comment: Thanks steeldriver, I recall seeing that property when I setup the X11 forwarding. Now that makes sense.